# Proving $\binom{2n}{n}<4^{n-1}$ for all positive integers $n\geq 5$

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-coefficients

For $n=5$, we get $\binom{10}{5}<4^4$. Asumme inductively that $\binom{2n}{n}<4^{n-1}$ for all positive integers $n\geq 5$. Then I need to prove that $\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}<4^{n}$ for all positive integers $n\geq 5$. I've been looking around a bit, and I've found that the expression $\binom{2n}{n}$ is precisely a central binomial coefficient. Thus $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}^2=\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}$. How can I use this to finish my proof?

Comment: To finish the proof you don't need that sum. You can just invoke the definition of binomial coefficients, and express $\binom {2(n+1)} {n+1}$ in terms of $\binom {2n}n$.

Comment: you can use combinatorics formula no? $\binom{2n}n = \frac{2n!}{n!(2n-n)!}$

Comment: @player3236  I get it. But is there a way to manipulate that sum to get the result?

Comment: @user29418 Yes, I can use this fact. But I'm interested to know if something can be done with the sum

Comment: With that sum it is trivial to see that $4^{n+1}$ is an upper bound. I don't see a direct way to reduce that to $4^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using inductive argument, you can do something simpler.

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$

Now prove that

$$\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}<4.$$

Once the inequality is proven, we can multiply both sides by $\binom{2n}{n}$ and get,
$$\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}<4\binom{2n}{n}\to \binom{2n+2}{n+1}<4\binom{2n}{n}$$

and using the inductive hypothesis we get,

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}<4\binom{2n}{n}<4\cdot4^{n-1}=4^n.$$

Comment: I think I follow Mr Arnaldo. In the first, you apply the inductive hypothesis and from there you get the second (since $4^n=4^{n-1}4$)(?). In the second part can I multiply by $(n + 1)$ on both sides and thus get what I need?

Comment: @Heriberto: You are almost there. You first prove the inequality, which is simple. Next step is multiply the inequality by $\binom{2n}{n}$ and then use the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: I've already managed all the steps. Sorry, but I don't see how one can conclude that the problem has been proven by taking the last step. :(

Comment: @Heriberto, please, check the update. Is it clear now?

Comment: Oh my goodness. Now everything is much clearer. This demonstration is very nice. Too bad I couldn't see it :(. Thank you Mr. Arnaldo.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Prove directly that
$
\dfrac{\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}<4
$
and conclude that
$
\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1} < 4 \binom{2n}{n}
$.

Comment: isn't that just ratio test?

Comment: And observe that this frightening expression is actually very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Lets think of this problem set theoretically.
Consider a set of $2n$ elements.
Then number all possible $n$-element subsets (subset whose cardinality is $n$) is ${2n}\choose{n}$.
The cardinality of the $power$ set (Set of all possible subsets) is $2^{2n}$ = $4^n$\

So clearly ${2n}\choose{n}$ $<$ $4^n$. But will it be less than $4^{n-1}$ $?$ (If yes then why?)